# How can I make "videosongs"?

Tags: software, video

Not purely audio, but definitely related!

Jack Conte and Nataly Dawn have "pioneered" the 'videosong' format.

- Rule 1 — What you see is what you hear. (No lip-syncing for instruments or voice)
- Rule 2 — If you hear it, at some point you see it. (No hidden sounds)

Example — [SEPTEMBER!!! by Earth Wind and Fire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xycnv87N_BU),

Can anyone suggest how these are made? Preferably with freeware for Windows...

Comment: Uhm. You film yourself recording, and then you edit that into a video. It's unclear what the question is.

Comment: What free software is capable of editing the videos? Windows Movie Maker doesn't cut it.

Comment: Reopened and cleared comments now that video production is on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Their main software tools are Pro Tools for audio and Final Cut Pro for video editing, on MacBook Pro.  Here's Jack's list of gear:  http://jackconte.tumblr.com/Gear

Jack and Nataly gave a tutorial on making videosongs at CELLspace in San Francisco for the Disposable Film Festival a few months ago.  Unfortunately only the song performances afterward have been posted to Youtube so far.  Perhaps if you contact DFF you can track down someone with video of the tutorial and Q&A session.

Perhaps another tool will be able to meet your requirements.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software

Answer (score 0):

You need a multi-camera setup and a video card that will receive simultaneous video feeds/channels. Then, multichannel video software which will probably need a very powerful CPU to run all channels with edits and effects.

Comment: Why would you need a multi-camera setup?

Comment: To capture more than one performer recording at the same time, which I assumed was the case with the Pomplamoose example.

Comment: You could also record on several file based cameras, and use the clip syncing feature in FPCX to line them all up.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about how the audio is recorded for these videos.  It appears to be just video clips taken from the recording session arranged into a music video.  It does look cool but that's all it is.

The best people to ask about video tools would be the band themselves!