# Combining multiple Videos

Tags: software, video

Does any one know about any free software for windows with which I can combine multiple videos and create a video like this?

Comment: Its a shame you didn't get a better answer.  What did you end up using?  I imagine this stuff can be done with Final Cut quite well.  Syncing the audio will be the hardest part, and may be better done separately in something like Pro Tools... But I agree, should be a single app to do this.  More info here. http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/895/how-to-make-videosongs

Comment: I didn't get anything yet... Thanks for the link though... :)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, for free, your best (albeit complicated) bet might be [Blender](http://blender.org).

You could create a series of several plane meshes in the layout you wanted, in front of the camera. You'd then create a separate material for each of the planes, setting them to shadeless, and giving each a [different video texture](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3aManual/Textures/Types/Video). You'd have to mix the audio separately (Windows Movie Maker, or Blender also has a built in video editor).

**I'll note that using a 3D approach for something like this isn't ideal at all - a 2D compositing program like [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) would be much better** (Blender itself does have a [2D compositing component](http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-242/blender-composite-nodes/), but since it uses nodes instead of layers, it might actually be more difficult).

Answer (score 1):

There are several free or cheap video editing programs for Windows; Microsoft themselves provide [Windows Movie Maker](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other), and then as an opensource alternative there's [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).